# Display a dropdown list in IIS using Web Deploy 3.0

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

I'm trying to get a drop down list to display using web deploy 3.0. I'm fairly new to the whole web deploy process, but basically here's what I want to be able to do:

1. Project -> Build Deployment Package
2. In IIS, create a new web site and click "Import Application"
3. I should see a DropDownList for one of the parameters.

After reading several articles on the topic, notably this excerpt from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068.aspx):

> Enumeration - Enumeration allows you to limit the user’s input to a list of discrete possible values. Most UIs will implement this as a drop-down list box, where [...]. The syntax for Enumeration is:

```
<parameter name="Enumeration Parameter"> 
    <parameterValidation type="Enumeration" validationString="value1,value2,value3,value4" /> 
</parameter>
```

And, for testing purposes, I copied-and-pasted the code above into my parameters.xml file, which works fine for any other kind of parameter. The enumeration parameter shows up, but it's just a text box -- there isn't a drop down list. Is this just the expected behavior from the IIS import interface or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little investigating, I found that the issue was that Web Deploy isn't adding the `parameterValidation` node to the deployment package. I was able to get around this issue by unzipping the deployment package, manually adding the XML for validation, and zipping it back up. I'd love to find a less hacky way to do this, though.

Answer (score 5):

This post might be old. But if anybody having the same issue please change type="Enumeration" to kind="Enumeration". So your tag should be like

```
  <parameter name="Enumeration Parameter">
  <parameterValidation kind="Enumeration" validationString="values1,value2,value3"/>
  </parameter>
```